# Avalonia TreeGridView

Tags: avaloniaui, avalonia

I'm trying to use the Avalonia TreeGridView but can't figure out how to use it in an object with a different object collection.
https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia.Controls.TreeDataGrid
The example provided on the Docs is as follows:

```cs
public class Person
{
  //some properties
  ObservableCollection<Person> People{get;set;}
}
```

The class that I'm using is

```cs
public class Department
{
  //some properties
  ObservableCollection<SubDepartment> SubDepartments{get;set}
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Items controls can bind to any generic observable collection.  You have to define the ItemTemplate to adapt the generic type to the control. https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/controls/treeview-1

Comment: The docs is for treeview, i'm using treegridview

Comment: Oh, I see.  You are using a TreeDataGrid.  That's a beta control.  There's not a lot of documentation or usage of it, but if it behaves like a DataGrid, it's still the same thing.  It's an ItemsControl.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is actually a way to use TreeDataGrid. Basically, you need to create another type of collection called [FlatTreeDataGridSource](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/reference/controls/detailed-reference/treedatagrid/creating-a-flat-treedatagrid).

```
public FlatTreeDataGridSource<SubDepartment> SubDepartments { get; set; }
```

Using this collection, you need to define columns such as TextColumn, CheckBoxColumn or TemplateColumn. Good luck using it!